# Creating an iMessage app without using a storyboard

Tags: ios, swiftui, imessage-extension

I would like to create an iMessage app without using a storyboard, and preferably using SwiftUI for the view. I am following an answer in an [Apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654864), but I am not getting a view inside the iMessage window.

I changed my `Info.plist` to:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.message-payload-provider</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>MessagesViewController.swift</string>
    </dict>
```

A simple view controller:

```
import Messages
import SwiftUI

@objc (MessagesViewController)
class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let child = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
        child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(child.view)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            child.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            child.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            child.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
            ])
    }
```

And finally a simple SwiftUI view:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, Earth!")
    }
}
```

So far, no luck. Does anyone have an idea where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your Info.plist file.  You have specified `MessagesViewController.swift` as the `NSExtensionPrincipalClass`

This is the source file name, not the class name. You need to specify the class name (which is `MessagesViewController`) prefixed with your module name.

Change your `Info.plist` to

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.message-payload-provider</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).MessagesViewController</string>
    </dict>
```